# Using a passed variable in a query using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to take a variable passed from another page and use it in a PDO query.  The variable is the date the record was added and I'm trying to return all the newer records.  Do I use $_POST for this in PDO?

```
<?php
require_once('globals.php');

$date_added = $_POST['date_added'];

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM games WHERE date_added > $date_added");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);


?>
```

Comment: Does it work? If not: what's the  error you are seeing? One issue here is that you are taking user data directly in the query - use prepared statements or $dbh->quote()

Comment: Here's the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.

Comment: @DonS You never had a successful database connection to begin with. Did you actually call `new PDO()` somewhere, like in `globals.php`?

Comment: @DonS Even if it isn't a public form you should be binding `$date_added` in the prepared statement.

Comment: @johannes what about non-user data? is it OK to put in in the query as is?

Comment: @Michael, no I did not call new PDO().  I'll try that.  How do I bind the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually establish a connection to the database by creating a new PDO object into `$dbh`.  The code below assumes a database user and password as `$dbusername, $dbpassword` and database named `$nameofdb`.

`$date_added` is replaced in the `prepare()` call with a parameter `:dateadded`, then passed via an array to the `execute()` call.

Please read the documentation on both [`PDO::__construct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pdo.construct.php) and [`PDO::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
<?php
require_once('globals.php');

// Connect to MySQL via PDO
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$nameofdb;host=localhost", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$date_added = $_POST['date_added'];

// Replace `$date_added` with a parameter `:dateadded`
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM games WHERE date_added > :dateadded");
// bind $date_added and pass it into the execute() call inside an array
$sth->execute(array('dateadded'=>$date_added));

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael!  That works perfectly.  Thanks for the PDO links as well.

Comment: If I wanted to json the result instead of printing it would the code be:  
'$json=json_encode($result);'
instead of:
'print_r($result);'
For that last line?